# All combinations of arbitrary number of sets using for comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming, cartesian-product

Let's look at following source of code:

```
def foo(s1: Set[Int], s2: Set[Int], s3: Set[Int]): Set[Set[Int]] = {
  for {
    ss1 <- s1
    ss2 <- s2
    ss3 <- s3
  } yield Set(ss1, ss2, ss3)
}
```

How to define analogous function for `def foo(ss: Set[Int]*)` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's almost the same as the usual cartesian product, except that you have to cram all the results into sets instead of collecting them in ordered tuples:

```
/** Forms cartesian product of sets,
  * then collapses each resulting tuple into a set.
  */
def collapsedCartesian[A](sets: Set[A]*): Set[Set[A]] = sets match
  case Seq() => Set(Set.empty)
  case Seq(h, t @ _*) => for a <- h; b <- collapsedCartesian(t: _*) yield (b + a)
```

Note that here, the `+` adds an element to a set: `set + elem`, which is an oddly asymmetric operation to be denoted by such a symmetric symbol.

The outcome seems reasonably irregular:

```
collapsedCartesian(Set(1, 2), Set(3, 4)).foreach(println)
println("---")
collapsedCartesian(Set(1, 2), Set(1, 2)).foreach(println)
println("---")
collapsedCartesian(Set(1, 2, 3), Set(4, 5), Set(6, 7)).foreach(println)
println("---")
collapsedCartesian(Set(1, 2, 3), Set(2, 3, 4), Set(4, 5)).foreach(println)
```

gives:

```
Set(3, 1)
Set(4, 1)
Set(3, 2)
Set(4, 2)
---
Set(1)
Set(2, 1)
Set(2)
---
Set(7, 5, 1)
Set(6, 4, 2)
Set(6, 4, 1)
Set(7, 4, 1)
Set(6, 5, 1)
Set(7, 5, 3)
Set(7, 4, 2)
Set(6, 5, 2)
Set(6, 4, 3)
Set(7, 5, 2)
Set(7, 4, 3)
Set(6, 5, 3)
---
Set(5, 3, 1)
Set(5, 4, 2)
Set(5, 4, 1)
Set(4, 2)
Set(4, 1)
Set(5, 3)
Set(5, 3, 2)
Set(5, 4, 3)
Set(4, 2, 1)
Set(5, 2, 1)
Set(4, 3, 1)
Set(4, 3, 2)
Set(5, 2)
Set(4, 3)
```

Please don't ask how to do it in Spark, this exponentially exploding stuff is obviously useless for any dataset with more than just a couple of entries.